# Help! I made two groups of order 5

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

[image: Multiplication tables of the two groups]
So I was verifying that a group of order 5 is unique. However I did come up with two groups. I am pretty sure they are not isomorphic as one is abelian while the other is not. I verified it several times, but if I am wrong do tell me. I have put the Multiplication tables in the image.

Also I am from chemistry background, so if possible, please explain your answer in some detail.

Comment: An odd order group can not have an element of order $2$.

Comment: You can apply [Light's associativity test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light%27s_associativity_test) to check that the second table does not define a group.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, I am from chemistry background, would you please explain your answer.

Comment: Generally speaking, a group such that $x=x^{-1}$ for all $x$ is forcibly abelian, because $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=xyxy=(xy)(xy)^{-1}=e$, and therefore $yx=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}yx=xy$.

Comment: Would you consider using [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to transcribe your writing? I promise that it’s in your best interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second "group" is not a group:
$$(A_1*A_2)*A_3 = A_3*A_3 = A_4 $$
$$A_1*(A_2*A_3) = A_1*A_1 = e$$
so the operation is not associative

Answer (score 2):

In the non abelian group that you wrote down, we have $$a_1 a_2 = a_3$$ and $$a_1 a_3 = a_4.$$ Using the first relation in the second gives $$a_1 a_1 a_2 = a_4$$  i.e, $$a_2 = a_4$$ which contradicts the order of the group being 5.

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication table shows all the group properties except for associativity. Did you check that?

Comment: I did not check for associativity. 